# Defining url rules on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, url, static, rule-engine

I have all my static files in a folder called html in the root directory. I get the following error while trying to access the index.html in html folder:

```
-
INFO     2012-07-27 04:07:44,847 dev_appserver.py:2952] "GET /images/logo_footer.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Here is the folder structure:

[image: root app directory]

[image: html directory]

**Handler code in handlers folder:**

```
class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = '../html/index.html'

    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = ContentType.HTML_TEXT
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))
```

Here is the url rule for images on app.yaml:

```
- url: /.*
  script: notify.app

# image files
- url: /(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
  static_files: html/images/\1
  upload: html/images/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: In your folder structure image, I see an images directory. Is html the name of the parent directory?

Comment: @DanHolevoet I have added more info the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the `url : /.*` section to after the image files section in app.yaml. These are processed in order, and `/.*` matches everything, so the second `- url:` line is never used.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have another url that matched "/images/logo_footer.jpg" first, and that served an error.

Also, don't know what the \1 in your static_files path is.

Comment: The \1 is from a regular expression grouping. In this case it refers to the entire filename from the URL.